# selecting a single item from grouped linq query based on a condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq, grouping

I am struggling with a grouping linq query

I have this:

```
DateTime dateFrom = new Date(2014,8,2);
var GroupedPrices = Prices.Where(p => p.ArrivalDateFrom <= dateFrom
                    &&
                    p.ArrivalDateTo > dateFrom)
                    .GroupBy(p => p.ItemID);
```

I am trying to get to a single price of each ID - eg. in/from each group, based on the newest ValidFrom date of that price.
I have started by grouping them by their ItemID's (*not the individual price record id's)* but am struggling in working out how to grab just a single one based on that newest ValidFrom date. I thought I could order them before grouping, but wasn't sure that would stick after the grouping was done.. ie

expecting it will use a `Max(x=>x.ValidFrom)` type thing or `OrderByDescending(x=>x.ValidFrom).First()` but cant work that out

any help much appreciated

thanks

Comment: are the ID's unique?  If they are, grouping them doesn't do you much good

Comment: they are not, this is the prices table for all the items, i'll call that item id to be clearer on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you just need to select what you want, at the end, like so:

```
DateTime dateFrom = new Date(2014,8,2);
var GroupedPrices = Prices
    .Where(p => p.ArrivalDateFrom <= dateFrom && p.ArrivalDateTo > dateFrom)
    .GroupBy(p => p.ItemID)
    .Select(g => new{ ItemId = g.Key, NewestPrice = g.OrderByDescending(p => p.ValidFrom).First() });
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I get {"The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead."} - I simply need the entire price object in each group that has the newest ValidFrom date

Comment: my bad that does work, by setting FirstOrDefault(). thanks very much